# GitHub Actions - You have an error in your yaml syntax

Tags: yaml, github-actions

Running code from https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/quickstart

why does this code create a syntax error:

```
- name: Checkout code
    uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

but this is fine:

```
- name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

According to this [YAML How many spaces per indent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247535/yaml-how-many-spaces-per-indent)
there are no indentation requirements for YAML.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's correct that the number of spaces can be freely chosen, but for the same node it has to be equal.

This is a mapping with two keys:

```
name: Checkout code
uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

but if you write it like this:

```
name: Checkout code
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

then the `uses: ...` is seen as a continuation of the previous value for `name`. But it's invalid, because colons plus spaces aren't allowed in mapping values.

If it looked like that:

```
name: Checkout code
  more
```

it would be valid YAML, equal to:

```
name: Checkout code more
```

So inside of that mapping, always use the same amount of spaces.

May I also recommend my [short tutorial](https://www.yaml.info/learn/index.html)?

Comment: yaml must be prohibited