# What's wrong with my YAML syntax for an embedded shell script in my GitHub action?

Tags: yaml, github-actions

In my GitHub actions [workflow](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/actions/runs/1416344044/workflow), I have the following segment (under jobs/build/steps):

```
      - name: Install/Select GCC and G++
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install -y gcc-${{ matrix.gcc }} g++-${{ matrix.gcc }}
          echo "CC=/usr/bin/gcc-${{ matrix.gcc }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "CXX=/usr/bin/g++-${{ matrix.gcc }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "CUDAHOSTCXX=/usr/bin/g++-${{ matrix.gcc }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

GitHub fails to run this, emitting:

> Invalid workflow file
>
> You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 82

Now, I lifted this from another repository in which this [same code](https://github.com/ptheywood/cuda-cmake-github-actions/blob/master/.github/workflows/Ubuntu.yml) supposedly works... what' going on?

Comment: This seems related to the indentation, look at how many spaces you have before the `-` symbol at line 76 and at line 83.

Comment: @GuiFalourd: Oh, indentation matters? It's not just "any number of spaces"? I thought tought YAML [didn't care much](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/yaml/yaml_indentation_and_separation.htm) about indentation.

Comment: In that case I believe it matters, because there are many levels of jobs, steps and workflow variables. For example in your case, the step at line 83 is at the same indentation level as a job variable field, and as it didn't expect this field to be there, it returns an error.

Comment: @einpoklum Gotta love how that article copied [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42248984/347964) without honoring CC-BY-SA. What is not mentioned is that of course, keys/items of the same collection node must be at the same indentation level. All that is said is that there is no requirement on the depth of that indentation level, as long as it is at least one more space indented than the surrounding level. This is what you get when you take stuff out of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the relevant lines, starting from 68, some lines skipped:

```yaml
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install CUDA
        # .. snip ..

      - name: Install/Select GCC and G++
        run: |
          sudo apt-get install -y gcc-${{ matrix.gcc }} g++-${{ matrix.gcc }}
          echo "CC=/usr/bin/gcc-${{ matrix.gcc }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "CXX=/usr/bin/g++-${{ matrix.gcc }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "CUDAHOSTCXX=/usr/bin/g++-${{ matrix.gcc }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - name: CMake configure
```

`steps:` is part of a YAML mapping. The next line starts a YAML sequence which is two spaces more indented. Consequentially, that sequence is ended in line 82 with `- name: CMake configure`. I have no idea why GitHub shows that as line 83; if you copypaste it to an editor, that empty line is not there. Possibly a line ending issue but I am too lazy to fire up a hex editor to find out.

In any case, on line 82, the YAML parser ended the value of the mapping key `steps` and thus expects another mapping key or the end of the mapping. However, it finds a sequence item. That's your error.

You seem to intend the following sequence items to be part of `steps:`. If so, indent them to the same level as the previous items.