# What is the reason for Kubernetes error "a line break is expected" when updating ConfigMap?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I encountered an error like this when updating a Kubernetes ConfigMap (YAML), via a JSON file upload for the value content:

> a line break is expected (20:22) 17 | - 1 18 | - 683d 19 | data: 20 |
> file.json |+file.json: "{\n\t"key...-----------------------^ 21 | #
> key: string | __clone: true

Not sure what this could be, as I have verified the source file to be valid JSON.

*Method of ConfigMap creation:*
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the reason for this error was that, though the source JSON file was valid JSON, it contained tab characters (\t), that are not acceptable for YAML.

See here:

- Relevant answer on another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60179343/2125723
- Official spec.: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2777534