# Syntax error with simple pipeline - suggests an error with the file but works when I watch the video

Tags: github-actions

Embarrassed to be posting a question like this, however I am new to github actions and on writing my first pipeline, I continue to get the error below despite hte code being thesame as what is on the youtube video here, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hVG9z0fCac&list=PLArH6NjfKsUhvGHrpag7SuPumMzQRhUKY I was wondering if anything has changed.

`You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 4`

```
name: Hello world workflow

on:
    push:
        branches:
            - main
    pull_request:
        branches:
            -   main
    workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
    hello:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            -   uses: actions/checkout@v2
            -   name: hello world
                run: echo "Hello World"
                shell: bash

    goodbye:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        steps:
            -   name: goodbye world
                run:    echo "Goodbye world"
                shell:  bash
```

Ironically, on my second hello world file, this works, note how the  `on: push` is shown here.

```
name: hello-world
on: push
jobs:
  my-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: my-step
        run: echo "Hello World!"
```

Comment: I think the first file has an indent error. I think you are using 4 spaces instead of 2. You can also see this if you look at the spacing of your two files. Please see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42247535/yaml-how-many-spaces-per-indent

Comment: Just verified that workflow with https://www.yamllint.com/ and https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/. It's a valid workflow. Are you sure that this was the workflow with error "**You have an error in your yaml syntax on line 4**"?

Comment: The issue was to do with vs code, for some reason its not linting properly, where it should tab using 2 spaces, its using 4. When you look at it on vs code, appears as 2, but when you look at it from github repo on the browser, one can see its 4. Just one to bear in mind if anyone else encounters similar issues.